# WCF + Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to work with WCF service for Windows Phone 7 applications?

Any link would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick walkthrough of hooking a WP7 app up to a WCF service. Scroll right to his first tutorial.

[AfricanGeek Silverlight 3 Video Tutorials](http://www.africangeek.com/)

Joel Johnson's also started a series here.

[Begining WCF for Windows Phone Developers](http://www.j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2011/01/13/Begining-WCF-for-Windows-Phone-Developers.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Accessing WCF Data Services from WP7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/03/19/accessing-wcf-data-services-from-wp7-ctp.aspx)

[Reddit WP7](http://www.reddit.com/r/wp7dev/)

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible and there are many ways to do this.  a simple solution would be to create a wcf service using the webbinding to expose a restful service that takes and returns json.  consume this service via http on your wp7 app.