# Some scenario with WCF - am I thinking good and where to start?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I was wondering where I can start looking for some introduction/help/tutorials to WCF?

My application scenario is that I want to write Windows Phone 7 app which can save/get data into SQL Server. I assume that WCF is the right choice. At first screen I would like to make some simple login page based also on sql table

Comment: Duplicated see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775465/wcf-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to look at [ASP.Net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). It embraces HTTP and can be consumed easily across devices and platforms.